# How to display HTML in asp.net textbox?

Tags: html, asp.net, textbox, encode

Is there a way to display the html in a asp:texbox but not have the data changed?

For Example:

I load would load this text:

```
teText.Text = obj.Text
```

Onto a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="teText" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="62px" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
```

But want to see and edit it like this:t

> test test testz
> test test testz
> test test testztest test
>   testz
> test test testz,...

But actually get this:

```
test test testz<br><br>test test testz<br>test test testztest test testz<br><br>test test testz,...
```

In other words, I dont want to see the `<br>` but actually line break. I would like to store them as `<br>`.

The was using an HTML editor that load them as `<br>` but storing them as `&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;`. NOT what I wanted at all. It had too many features I dont need, so now I just want to use a simple editor that will allow me to view and edit in html and stored in database as `<br>`s.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a text editor, you need to manually replace the `<br>` with a line break `\r` or newline `\n`:

```
string test = "test test testz<br><br>test test testz<br>test test testztest test testz<br><br>";

teText.Text = test.Replace("<br>", "\n");
```

And in reverse

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = teText.Text.Replace("\n", "<br>");
}
```

Comment: it's not just the line breaks, it's the quotes and such too. the editor i was is similar to http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx. but again i don't need all that. just need the html. no other way other than to replace? what about javacript? jquery? thanks.

Comment: If it is all the html, go and use an editor. It will be so much easier than creating something yourself. And with most editors you can customize the UI.

Comment: hi, this is what i get 'test test testz\n\ntest test testz\ntest test testztest test testz\n\ntest test testz,...' doesn't show as mentioned.